# Windows -C# - Treeview without connecting lines

Tags: c#, windows, treeview

Is it possible to show parent node "without any lines or plus sign" and  adding child nodes under same parent node which have showplusMinus enalbed.

like :

(ParentNode)

```
  +Child1

  +Child2

  +Child3
```

Comment: Why don't you mark the answer below? did it not solve your problem?

Answer (score 8):

Set the ShowLines property to false.

[TreeView.ShowLines Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.showlines.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating
>   whether lines are drawn between tree
>   nodes in the tree view control.

Comment: Thanks astander, if I want to show parent node "without any lines and plus sign" .but I need to show plus sign for child nodes which are to be added under parent node .would that also be possible.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with the standard control, but it is no doubt possible if you can spend the time building a custom control. e.g. make each top level node a label, and child nodes a subtree with ShowLines set to false. Sounds messy, but should be possible.